# How to check if user bought a product offered by IAP

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In my application I offer the user to make a donation using Google Play IAP, in return I remove ads and unlock premium features.

When my application loads I want to check if user made a donation, how to do that via code **knowing that** after user makes a donation I'll call the following code to allow the user to make future donations if desired.

So, I want to allow the user to make further donations if desired, but I want to know if (s)he already made a donation to disable ads and unlock premium features.

```
BillingProcessor bp;
bp.consumePurchase(productId);
```

Note, my questions is about IAP online process not about saving a value offline and check it later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this guide should help show you how to do this:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

> **Query cached purchases**
>
> To retrieve information about purchases that a
>   user makes from your app, call the queryPurchases() method with the
>   purchase type (SkuType.INAPP or SkuType.SUBS) on the Play Billing
>   Library client. For example:
>
> `PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.INAPP);`
>
> Google Play returns the
>   purchases made by the user account logged in to the device. If the
>   request is successful, the Play Billing Library stores the query
>   results in a List of Purchase objects.
>
> Note: Only active subscriptions appear on this list. As long as the
>   in-app product is on this list, the user should have access to it. For
>   further information, refer to Handle SUBSCRPTION_ON_HOLD section of
>   the Add subscription-specific features document. To retrieve the list,
>   call the getPurchasesList() method on the PurchasesResult object. You
>   can then call a variety of methods on the Purchase object to view
>   relevant information about the item, such as its purchase state or
>   time. To view the types of product detail information that are
>   available, see the list of methods in the Purchase class.
>
> Call queryPurchases() at least twice in your code:
>
> Every time your app launches so that you can restore any purchases
>   that a user has made since the app last stopped. In your onResume()
>   method because a user can make a purchase when your app is in the
>   background (for example, redeeming a promo code in Play Store app).
>   Calling queryPurchases() on startup and resume guarantees that your
>   app finds out about all purchases and redemptions the user may have
>   made while the app wasn't running. Furthermore, if a user makes a
>   purchase while the app is running and your app misses it for any
>   reason, your app still finds out about the purchase the next time the
>   activity resumes and calls queryPurchases().
>
> **Query most recent purchases**
>
> The queryPurchases() method uses a cache
>   of the Google Play Store app without initiating a network request. If
>   you need to check the most recent purchase made by the user for each
>   product ID, you can use the queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() method and
>   pass the purchase type and a PurchaseHistoryResponseListener to handle
>   the query result.
>
> queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() returns the most recent purchase made by
>   the user for each product ID, even if that purchase is expired,
>   cancelled, or consumed. Use the queryPurchases() method whenever
>   possible, as it uses the local cache, instead of the
>   queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() method. You could combine
>   queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() with a Refresh button allowing users to
>   update their list of purchases.
>
> The following code demonstrates how you can override the
>   onPurchaseHistoryResponse() method:

```
 mBillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(SkuType.INAPP,
                                          new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(@BillingResponse int responseCode,
                                           List purchasesList) {
         if (responseCode == BillingResponse.OK
                 && purchasesList != null) {
             for (Purchase purchase : purchasesList) {
                 // Process the result.
             }
          }
     } });
```

Comment: Thank you nasch ... I found this about onPurchaseHistoryResponse

queryPurchaseHistoryAsync won't do what you need because it will only give you a list of the most recent purchases for each SKU. They may have expired, been cancelled or been consumed, and there's no way to tell. Therefore this response can't be used to tell what purchases to apply in your app.

Comment: Yeah I see.  The only other suggestions I have then are to look at what comes back in the "original JSON" in the Purchase object (this is not documented so I can't tell without running tests myself), or look through the Trivial Drive sample code and see if there's anything useful there.

Comment: What you need it the `queryPurchasesAsync`. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS); //Or SkuType.INAPP

            if (purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {

                        if (purchase.getSku().equals("your_product_id")) handlePurchase(purchase);

                }

[...]

void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            premium = true; //In casse purchase was acknowledge before
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                        AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .build();

                AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
                        premium = true;
                    }
                };

                billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you have any questions, go ahead and comment.

Answer (score 3):

As nasch and AlexBSC already answered, you have to fetch for possible made purchases.

However, the most up to date method of doing this is calling `BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()` as described in [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#fetch). You should at least call it in `onResume()` and `onCreate()`.

for example like this,

```
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, new PurchasesResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == OK
                    && purchases != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    handlePurchase(purchase);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Following [these steps](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) should get you pretty far.